# Running Python unittest with PyCharm and command line options

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been running my Python 2.7 unit tests like this

```
python -m unittest discover -s tests -b
```

I would like to run them in PyCharm, however, I cannot figure out how to send the -b [buffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.buffer) option to the PyCharm test runner. I've tried numerous setups in the Run/Debug Configurations without success.

How do I configure running unit tests in PyCharm so that every time I run 'Unittests in test' it is run with the -b argument?

[image: Unittests]

Comment: If you enable the `Params` checkbox and use `--buffer` from `Run/Debug`. Does that work?

Comment: @idjaw The runner runs this `/myvenv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py /development/myapp/ --buffer true` but it doesn't work as I have a test that passes with the option but fails here.

Comment: Also did not find how to fix this. But in order not to distract the unloading of all prints, I unchecked the 'Activate tool windows' checkbox in the 'Run/Debug Configuration' settings.